# How to know how many tablespoons of seeds correspond to 1 table spoon of its ground form?

Tags: spices, conversion

Please point out a conversion method or the Google keywords which would result in a **trusted** measuring chart for converting seeds to powder or paste form or vice versa.

Example:
1 tablespoon of powdered Coriander seeds correspond to how many tablespoons of raw Coriander seeds.

Comment: Anisha, this is one I just wouldn't worry about.  Any *quality* recipe where the amount is critical will give you weight measurements, not volume, and these are of course exactly the same pre-groudn and ground.   Otherwise, just give it an eye estimate--if you are slightly under you can grind some more; if slightly over, save the extra.  And in most recipes, it doesn't matter for the chemistry or outcome, just the flavor, which you would adjust anyway.

Comment: Hard to get an accurate chart since Seed sizes and their hollowness vary as does grind fineness; all affecting the volume. As Saj14saj noted, weighing is the best option. My guess is coriander seeds drop to 1/3 or so.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I'm sorry, but I really wouldn't expect to see weights for spices even in most good recipes and cookbooks. It's a nice idea in theory, but people just don't do it. And in practice it might not even be useful, since spice quantities often get down into the fraction of a gram range, and virtually no one has scales that precise in their kitchens.

Comment: @Jefromi I would in professional quality scalable recipes.   But the point is, at home it just doesn't matter that much at home scales.

Comment: I found these links, might be helpful: 1. http://www.cooking-with-us.com/spiceconversion.php#   2. http://www.smithandtruslow.com/spice_conversions.php

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/15865/1672 -  I'm not sure if the answers there will satisfy you, though. The non-accepted answer is the only one that actually answers the question, and it does have a rule of thumb that's probably mostly good enough.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how accurate you want, but based upon the book `On Food And Cooking: The Science And Lore Of The Kitchen by Harold McGee`, this is not possible to be 100% accurate. This is probably too accurate for your needs, but as you didn't state how accurate you want, I'll only explain why it can't be 100% accurate.

Measuring by tablespoons or the like doesn't take into consideration the size of the food on the spoon (the seed in this case). For example, not every seed has the same shape, size or mass. So when grinding to a powder, you're not working with consistent seeds.

This means, if you take 1tbs (or ever better, a cup) or seeds and then weight it, and then take another measure you'll have different results.

The problem with powder, is it depends on how fine you're going. The finer will allow you have more powder in the same space compared to something 'grated' a little thicker. There is also the issue of air which gets into the powders which will have some factor.